# VBA SumIfs not working with Date range

Tags: vba, excel

So, I have tried many variations, but I can't make this work:

```
var_sum = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("H:H"), Range("B:B"), str_client, Range("A:A"), "<=" & date_var)
```

This formula has 2 conditions. The second one (date comparison) breaks it and makes the sum = 0. 
date_var is a Date variable.
The date range in Excel is formatted as Date.

What could be wrong?

Comment: It seems like it should work. If you enter the same formula in Excel does it work? If you do a simple comparison of `date_var` with the values in `A:A` are some of them less than `date_var`?

Comment: Is your date in Excel date format (the decimal of Days and hours from 1/1/1900 12:00:00 A.M.)

Comment: This is working for me. Please describe what is not working about it? Also, might be helpful to post A) more of your code and B) example worksheet data.  Otherwise, the formula evaluates. But without knowing more about what you think is not working, and without seeing the data you're working with, it's kinda impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: @DougGlancy Yes I can make it work in Excel, but using the DATE formula in the comparison ("<=" & DATE(..))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a feeling you have a string with the date.

```
Date_Var = "01/01/2013"
```

you could try using `CDate(` or `CLng(` to convert it to the appropriate value, as Excel stores dates as number of days past Jan 1, 1900

```
var_sum = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("H:H"), Range("B:B"), str_client, _
    Range("A:A"), "<=" & CLng(date_var))
```

Comment: You were right, thanks. I had tried CDate before and it does not work. I always have a headache with dates and number formats. Does it mean I can always convert it to Long and compare to other dates?

Comment: yes - change a date to **General** format, and you can see that it's a number (fractional if a time is also present) - e.g. Today is actually 41367 ( use `CDbl(` if you have to use time in your comparison)

Comment: Thanks, Add this issue to. I also tried CDate, didn't thought about Clng