# Sumifs with date criteria

Tags: vba, excel, date, sumifs

I'm trying to use the `Sumifs` function on my VBA code, but it is failing when the criteria is a date.

I have two strings representing month and year like `jan/2016` and `feb/2016`.

And I convert them to date to get a "real" date like `01/01/2016` and `01/02/2016`

```
month1 = CDate(string1)
month2 = CDate(string2)
```

My range is a column which is formatted as Date (`DateRange`) with values like `04/01/2016`, `13/01/2016`, ...

And the code is:

```
sumifs1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range1,
    Range2, var,
    DateRange, ">=" & month1,
    DateRange, "<" & month2)
```

This works (return a value) if I don't put the dates, but I have to limit the sum by a period.

I already tried change the number format of the date column like this:

```
DateRange.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
DateRange.NumberFormatLocal = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Tried to format my months like this:

```
month1 = Format$(CDate(string1), "dd/mm/yyyy")
month2 = Format$(CDate(string2), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

But nothing works (returns 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this way:

```
month1 = CLng(CDate(string1))
month2 = CLng(CDate(string1))

sumifs1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range1,
    Range2, var,
    DateRange, ">=" & month1,
    DateRange, "<" & month2)
```

Thanks to @SeanC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15790594/3050951)

Comment: That's the same approach I use when dealing with dates in Office programs... Dates are stored as `Double` values, where the integral part is the number of days elapsed since January 1st, 1900 and the decimal part is the day fraction (i.e. `0.5` means `12:00:00 PM`)

Answer (score 0):

With dates in column **A** and values in column **B**, then in this example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A20>=DATEVALUE("1/1/2016"))*(A1:A20<DATEVALUE("2/1/2016"))*(B1:B20))
```

[image]

Yields the sum of the column **B** values within the date range.

In *VBA*:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, d1 As Date, d2 As Date
    Dim N As Long, ss As String
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    s1 = "jan/2016"
    s2 = "feb/2016"
    d1 = CDate(s1)
    d2 = CDate(s2)

    Set r1 = Range("A1:A20")
    Set r2 = Range("B1:B20")

    For Each r In r1
        If r.Value >= d1 And r.Value < d2 Then
            N = N + r.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next r

    MsgBox N
End Sub
```

will yield the same result.

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up converting it to Long. I found it more easy.

Comment: Date format depends on regional configuration, so it's better to convert to a number (`Long` or `Double`) to ensure the code works independent of regional config.